# Cutting a rectangular piece from a right triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, rectangles

A piece of sheet metal has the shape of an acute right-angled triangle AB with side BC and height AA' each having 12 cm. From it, a rectangle with two vertices is cut on the base BC and the other two on AB, respectively AC. Calculate the perimeter of this rectangle.

**MY DRAWING**

[image]

Okey, so, we know that MNPQ a rectangle(I named the points that made the rectangle M,N,P,Q). MN is parallel with AB and applying the the fundamental theorem of similarity, wecan say that the traingle MAQ is similar with CAB.

What should I do next??? Any idea is welcome! Thank you!

Comment: Take a constant $\lambda$ so that $AM=\lambda AB$ and surely $AN=\lambda AC$. What are the sides of the rectangle? Use the fact that $AA'=BC=12 cm$ (to get two lambdas to cancel each other).

Comment: @StinkingBishop i dont really understand... can you exemplify it....like writing in answers?

Comment: I could, but I don't know how exactly similarity is explained to you and which theorems you know, so whatever I write may be incomprehensible to you, and therefore not useful. In my comment above, I simply give the letter $\lambda$ to the common ratio $\lambda=AM:AB=AN:AC$. Can you see that (a) $MQ=NP=\lambda BC$, (b) Height of $\triangle AMQ$ is $\lambda AA'$; (c) $MN=PQ=AA'-\lambda AA'=(1-\lambda)AA'$. Now add all those together and use that $AA'=BC=12cm$.

Comment: A "cheating" way to find the answer: since the question implies it doesn't matter how $M$ or $Q$ is chosen, the answer must be the same when the rectangle is close to the two extremes: very short and near segment $AB$, or very narrow and near segment $AA'$. In either case, the perimeter approaches $24$ cm. So that must be the constant answer!

Comment: I want to check a couple of things. First, you atated that $MN$ is parallel to $AB$, but this is not true. Based on the rest of that sentence, did you mean $MQ$ is parallel to $CB$? Second, "acute right-angled triangle" isn't clear. Triangles are one of acute-, right- or obtuse-angled. I think in this case it's enough for $ABC$ to be an acute-angled triangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Image of triangle]

Mark point $X$ as the intersection of $AA'$ and $MQ$.

$MQ$ is parallel to $CB$ so $ABC$ and $AQM$ are similar triangles (as stated in the question).

$AA'=BC$, hence $MQ=AX$ by similar triangles. Clearly $XA'=QP$ so we have $AA=AX+XA'=MQ+QP=12$cm.

Since $MQ+QP$ is half the perimeter of $MNPQ$ the full perimeter is $24$cm.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some proportions obtained from similar triangles:

$$\frac{MN}{AA'} = \frac{CM}{CA} \\
\frac{MQ}{CB} = \frac{AM}{CA}$$

Add up the LHS above and get
$$\frac{MN}{AA'} + \frac{MQ}{CB} = \frac{CM+ AM}{CA}=1$$

In your case $AA'= CB$, so we get the perimeter of the rectangle constant, no matter how is situated.

[image: rectangle in triangle]

$\bf{Added:}$ Say we introduce some coordinates on the height $AA'$. Then the perimeter of the rectangle corresponding to a point on the height is an affine function. But note that it takes equal values at $A$ and at $A'$. It follows that it is a constant function.